# How do you move an app shortcut between launcher screens?

Tags: home-screen, launcher

So I have a few icons and folders on the leftmost launcher screen.  I want to move them to the middle one.  You'd think that you'd do it by dragging the icons to the dots on the lower left/ lower right corner, but that doesn't work.

I know it's possible to do because I've actually done it few times, somehow, but I can't figure out how to do it in any kind of reliable way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drag the icon to the edge, not the corners.  It can be a little finicky depending on the particular touchscreen hardware your phone has.

Comment: Finicky is an understatement. I've given over trying to do it that way and just long-press from the app drawer.

Comment: Yeah depending on how many screens I want to move it (more than one) I'll just delete it and long press from the app drawer :)

Comment: I'm lazy, I'll drag an icon from the far left to the far right just because I don't have to pick up my thumb more than once that way ;)